# PHP Counting MYSQL rows issue?

Tags: php, mysql, rows, counting

I am trying to make it to if I have at least 1 team created for one person, it will display the team. If they don't have a team, it will say no teams. It works if the person has at least 1 team, but nothing shows if the person is not on a team. How do I fix this?

```
<?php

                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE players LIKE '%$sessiongamt%'") or die("Could not allocate information!");
                                $num = 0;
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                                    $num = ++$num;
                        $amount1 = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                        $name = $row["name"];
                                    $teamrank = $row["rank"];
                                    $teamlink = $row["link"];
                                    $players = $row["players"];
                        $teamid = $row['id'];

                        if($amount1 < 1){
                          $teams = "No Teams";
                          echo "$amount";
                        }else{
                          $teams = "$name";
                          echo "<a href='$teamlink?id=$teamid'>$teams</a>";
                        }


                      }print "$amount1";
                    ?>
```

Comment: Why using `$num = ++$num;`? why not `$num++` ?

Comment: Please show your table structures.  We won't be able to help without them.  Or at least it would be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the third line of this code - put it in your code on the same place instead of your line.

```
                        if($amount1 < 1){
                          $teams = "No Teams";
                          echo $teams;
                        }else{
                          $teams = "$name";
                          echo "<a href='$teamlink?id=$teamid'>$teams</a>";
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the counting outside the while... loop

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE players LIKE '%$sessiongamt%'") or die("Could not allocate information!");

$amount1 = mysql_num_rows($sql);  //<---- this should fix it

$num = 0;        
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $num = ++$num;

    $name = $row["name"];
    $teamrank = $row["rank"];
    $teamlink = $row["link"];
    $players = $row["players"];

    $teamid = $row['id'];

    $teams = "$name";
    echo "<a href='$teamlink?id=$teamid'>$teams</a>";
}

if($amount1 < 1){
   $teams = "No Teams";
}

print "$amount1";
?>
```

Comment: Try using an alternative library to `mysql_`. Use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: It shows the team name if there is one, otherwise, it just shows the number of teams(0)